# No sound over HDMI running 15.04 on NUC D54250WYK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

After upgrading to 15.04, and maybe another update round, I can't hear any sound over HDMI. A sound device seems to exist:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But when I try to play something (with aplay) there's nothing but silence (not even an error). I already looked at volume controls and nothing is muted or low-volume as far as I can see.

PulseAudio Volume Control doesn't seem to recognize any output device existing at all except Built-In Audio Analog Stereo, and the sound settings don't even recognize that.

Things I've already tried:

- An update via apt-get didn't solve this.
- pavucontrol didn't display an HDMI device.
- aplay lists a device but doesn't seem to play anything.
- deleting files in ~/.pulse dirs didn't help.
- restarting alsa and pulseaudio didn't help either.

Here is the also-info.sh report from my computer:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=4750eeb7df3a6ffcb40d9debd7c001556a8d93fb

Comment: ALSA appears to **not** have loaded any intel hda HDMI decive. The device you see is just the default analog audio. Sadly I can't tell you why this is but it definitely is an ALSA issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the result of a kernel bug Ubuntu's kernel version 3.19.0-18. The issue was fixed in a later update.